# External Python Libraries Not Detected by AWS Lambda Functions

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, libraries

I am trying to use PyMuPDF in my lambda function on AWS.

I have used this youtube video to try to integrate the library as a layer so it will work on my lambda function. [How to install Pandas on AWS Lambda function](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1UDEp90S9h8) (in a nutshell: ZIP the linux library package and then save it a layer & then apply that layer to your function)

I have obtained the library from [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/PyMuPDF/) and have tried using the latest and older version and both of them does not work.

The ZIP file contains these two folders which are unpacked from the PyPI

```
Python_library.zip
│ python_library/PyMuPDF
└ python_library/PyMuPDF-1.18.10.dist-info
```

Does anyone know what am I doing wrongly? Some help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Wow, you made the solution to my problem so easy.  Thanks for asking this question.  If I could upvote again and again I would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the folder in zip is `python` instead of `python_library`.

In [aws-doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-path):

```
The following examples show how you can structure the folders in your layer .zip archive.

pillow.zip
│ python/PIL
└ python/Pillow-5.3.0.dist-info
```

This worked for me:

- Python3.7

```
python.zip
└── python/
    ├── fitz/
    └── PyMuPDF-1.19.0.dist-info/
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Nice simple solution.